# Excel data indexing and retrieval across multiple sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to pull the data using a IF/Vlookup formula from other sheets. So, I have three sheets in total, two of which contain the age of men and women. The other sheet contains the names of men, women and their age. The formula should give me their age corresponding to their name (retrieved from the relevant sheets). If my data that I input is not in men or women, then it should "Not Applicable".

I tried using the the IF OR formula with loops as well, but it appears the it does not give me a proper result.

Appreciate any help on this!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here assuming that you have one worksheet for men, the other for women. For demo, I just put them in one worksheet.

```
=IFERROR(1/SUMPRODUCT(($D$2:$D$5=A2)*$E$2:$E$5+($G$2:$G$5=A2)*$H$2:$H$5)^-1,"Not Applicable")
```

[image]